# Adding a one single div, wrapper or containing element around all repeated fields in an Advanced Custom Fields Repeater

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I've been trying to add an Id or class around an entire Repeater field, so that I might be able to style the 'repeated elements' via grid.  At the most it will only have 3 groups in the Repeater. I'm thinking it might be some sort of If statement or counter.  I've even found posts demonstrating how to add a container around every second or third one; but nothing shows how to wrap the entire repeater.
Everything I try just adds a div or Id around each repeated field, and does not contain all of the repeated groups.  I would like to have an id of 'multiple', where as that Id wraps around the whole repeater.

Here is my latest code that I tried, which is obviously not right.  I've moved the div all around, and tried css too.

```
    <?php  //begin some repeating fields for if multiple trips to same country 
            elseif (get_row_layout() == 'trip_card') : ?>

<div id="multiple">
    <?php if (have_rows('multiple_trips')) :
                        // loop through the rows of data
                        while (have_rows('multiple_trips')) : the_row();

                            //vars
                            $first_trip_title = get_sub_field('first_trip_title');
                            $first_trip_date = get_sub_field('first_trip_date');

                            //display a sub field value 
                    ?>

    <p><strong><?php echo $first_trip_title; ?>:</strong></p>

    <p><?php echo $first_trip_date; ?></p>
</div><!-- end of multiple -->
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: The placing of the opening tag looks alright - but the closing one probably gets output too early and multiple times, because you placed it _inside_ the while loop? (I am guessing, because I do not see the corresponding `endwhile` anywhere - so I suppose it must come further down, otherwise this code probably would not run in the first place.)

Comment: @CBroe thank you! You are exactly right!  I did solve it by placing it _outside_ of the while loop, and posted the new code.  Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this but maybe this might help someone! I was making it WAY harder then it was!

Here is what I did to get a class called ‘multiple’ or wrapper around my repeater:

```
<?php 

// begin some repeating fields for if multiple trips to same country
elseif(get_row_layout() == 'trip_card'):

    // if have multiple_trips rows
    if(have_rows('multiple_trips')):
             
        // begin .multiple wrapper       
        echo '<div class="multiple">';

            // loop through the multiple_trips rows
            while (have_rows('multiple_trips')) : the_row();

                // variables
                $first_trip_title = get_sub_field('first_trip_title');
                $first_trip_date = get_sub_field('first_trip_date');
               
                // display a sub field value 
                echo '<div>' . ( $first_trip_title ?? '<strong>' . $first_trip_title . '</strong>' ) . $first_trip_date . '</div>';

            // endwhile multiple_trips loop
            endwhile;

        // close .multiple wrapper
        echo '</div>';

    // else multiple_trips rows 
    else:
            
        // no multiple_trips rows found 
            
    // endif multiple_trips rows      
    endif;

// endif get row layout trip_card
endif;
```